# Custom Fields not showing up when having multiple Signers on DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I have following code. I am using a template with one PDF and I want to add values to certain specific places in the PDF before getting it signed. I want to embed this in my own VueJS app. I have couple customFields named amount, customerName, etc. When I open the embed code on an iframe, I don't see the customFields. Do you see anything wrong with my code so far? Thanks in advance.

```
const docusign = require('docusign-esign');

export const makeEnvelope = async (data) => {

    let payload = {
        signerEmail: 'a@b.com',
        signerName: 'a b',
        agentName: 'a c',
        agentEmail: 'a@c.com',
        templateId: 'xxx'
    }

    let env = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
    env.templateId = payload.templateId;

    let info = {
        "amount": "143",
        "customerName": "ccc",
        "tax": "13"
    }

    let textFields = [];

    Object.keys(info).forEach(i => {
        let text = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
            tabLabel: i, value: info[i]
        });
        textFields.push(text);
    })

    let tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
        textTabs: textFields,
    });

    let customer = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
        name: 'sq',
        email: 's@q.com',
        Name: 'sq',
        signerName: 'sq',
        roleName: 'customer',
        tabs: tabs

    });

    let agent = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
        name: 'sa',
        email: 's@a.com',
        Name: 'sa',
        signerName: 'sa',
        roleName: 'agent',
        tabs: tabs
    });

    env.templateRoles = [agent, customer];
    env.status = "sent";

    return env;
    }

export const docuApi = async (event) => {

    let payload = {
        basePath: 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi',
        accessToken: 'ccc',
        accountId: 'xxx',
    };


    let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
    await dsApiClient.setBasePath(payload.basePath);
    await dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + payload.accessToken);
    let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient);

    let envelope = await makeEnvelope(payload.envelopepayload);

    let envelopeId;
    let results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(payload.accountId, {envelopeDefinition: envelope})
        .then(res => {
            envelopeId = res.envelopeId;
        })
        .catch(err => {
        });

    console.log('envelopeId', envelopeId);

    let viewRequest = await makeRecipientViewRequest({
        "dsReturnUrl": '',
        "signerEmail": 's@q.com',
        "signerName": 'sa',
        // "signerClientId": '',
        "dsPingUrl": 'https://example.com'
    })

    let createView = await envelopesApi.createRecipientView(
        payload.accountId, envelopeId,{recipientViewRequest: viewRequest})
        .then(res => {
            console.log('createView res', res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response.error);
        });    
    return results;

}

const makeRecipientViewRequest = async (args) => {    
    let viewRequest = new docusign.RecipientViewRequest();
    viewRequest.returnUrl = args.dsReturnUrl + "?state=123";
    viewRequest.authenticationMethod = 'none';
    viewRequest.email = args.signerEmail;
    viewRequest.userName = args.signerName;
    viewRequest.clientUserId = args.signerClientId;

    viewRequest.pingFrequency = 600; // seconds
    viewRequest.pingUrl = args.dsPingUrl; // optional setting

    return viewRequest
}
```

Comment: Siva, when you created this template, did you add the same tabs to the first signer that you're updating with this call? These tabs have to already exist in the template, and you're just updating their values with this call....

Comment: Yes, I added the tabs beforehand and assigned it to the first signer "agent". When I open the embed link in InCognite window, I don't see any of the agent tabs/customFields and I see "In Progress" in the middle of the PDF.

Comment: aha, this may indicate that the view is not for this signer. Let me look at your code again

Comment: can you confirm that the email and userName you have match exactly to the first recipient? that could be the reason it's not generating this for the correct user

Comment: Holy cow, that worked. I had tried userName and signerClientId but those didn't work but clientUserId worked. DocuSign has used different names to refer to the same thing in different spots. I understand they have different context but it is confusing. 
Thank you for your help. Now, I just have to create different views for each signer using returnUrls. There isn't another way to get 3 people in the same place to sign on the same view, right?

Comment: I posted an answer, please mark as answered.

Comment: and no, you have to create 3 views if you want 3 different people, the view is for a specific recipient

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the userName and clientUserId must match the template. Otherwise the view that is generated doesn't match the recipient and you won't get to be able to interact with it, it will only show "In Progress".
The view is specific for a specific recipient, for each recipient you would have to generate their own view.